# What's the first movie to show trailer of its sequel/prequel at the end?

Tags: first-appearance

At the end of "The Matrix Reloaded (2003)", there is a trailer of its sequel i.e
"The Matrix Revolutions (2003)".

What's the first movie to show trailer of its sequel/prequel at the end?

Comment: Back to the Future II showed scenes from Back to the Future III at the end, I'm fairly sure, but I don't know whether it was the first.

Comment: Doubtful if there is a definitive answer about trailers but The Three Musketeers (1973), if I recall, included a promo for the sequel which was already filmed.